# ASP.Net MVC restrictions on words used within a model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have inherited a database - which has "ref" and "2parq" as fields.

When building a model to represent this database table, I get the error:

`Invalid token 'ref' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

My Class is below:

```
public class Call
{
    [Key]
    public int CallId { get; set; }
    public string ref { get; set; }
```

Renaming the database field isn't an option unfortunately.

Is there anyway I can reference the "ref" and "2parq" fields within my model?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public string @ref { get; set; }
```

`@` symbol will tell the compiler, it should ignore the reserved keyword `ref` and treat it as a regular variable.

`MSDN` documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `@ref`, I would recommend using a correct PascalCase property name, and change the mapping using either the `Column` attribute, or better still the fluent mapping API.

```
[Column(Name="ref")]
public string Reference { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `@` symbol to the property name:

```
public class Call
{
    [Key]
    public int CallId { get; set; }
    public string @ref { get; set; }
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is
>   useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The
>   character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier
>   might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the
>   prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim
>   identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords
>   is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.

Comment: Thank you - that worked for the "ref" column, but not the "2parq" column, if I change to "@2parq" - I still get the error: the type or namespace "parq" could not be found - thank you, Mark

Comment: Didn't follow up this one, sorry. In C# you can not have identifiers starting with number - so you'd really have to use devdigital's suggestion (although I'm still not sure it will work for column name starting with number).